# Is a storage location considered like an actor in use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm creating  diagrams for software which check if there is a certificate in certificate stores (Windows), then import it. My question is can I consider certificate stores as a non-human actor in use case diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An actor in a uml diagram represents a role that interacts with your application. So, if your certificate store interacts with your application then it can be considered an actor. If it doesn't interact then it is really just a node in a class diagram.

Comment: Thanks, as I know database is considered an actor if it is outside the application (is not part of the developed software). So surely the certificate store is outside the application, is it an actor?

Comment: If the certificate store interacts with the application then there will be use cases that start with "The certificate store does xxx". In that case it will be an actor. If all it is used for is storing data then it won't be an actor.

Comment: Not Class diagram, but Deployment and Component diagrams. The class diagram is far below that level.